# Firefox asks for proxy details, but only when accessing facebook

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, proxy

At work, all requests are forwarded to a central load-balancing, caching Squid proxy server. If I try to access Facebook from within Firefox, I get the standard proxy authentication dialog:

```
The proxy moz-proxy://<IP addresss> is requesting a username and password. 
The site says: "moz-proxy://<IP Address>"
```

However, this dialog comes *only* for facebook & only when accessed from Firefox - any clues as to why this happens? Accessing from Internet Explorer or Chrome **works fine**, and yes Facebook is *not* blocked.

Just Firefox gives this problem. I have installed [NTLM Auth for Firefox addon](http://code.google.com/p/firefox-ntlmauth/), but it hasn't helped.

The proxy settings are set to auto detect, same as in Internet Explorer & Chrome.

I'm using the current stable version of Firefox, 10.0.2 on Windows XP SP3

Comment: @Sathya: Perhaps they are attempting to block Facebook? Hear if it also happens for other employees using Firefox (as I suppose hearing at the IT administrator if the company's policy has changed is kind of not what you want to be doing).

Comment: @TomWijsman it isn't blocked - I've mentioned it works fine on IE & Chrome.

Comment: @Sathya: Strange that it only happens in Firefox though, you might get around using [IE Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/ie-tab/). (Please note that there are multiple IE Tab add-ons and I'm unsure which is the right one or which works...)

Comment: And this is only happening on a single computer?

Comment: @iglvzx it's my work system - I don't have other systems to test it out

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your Connection Settings? `chrome://browser/content/preferences/connection.xul` ... If you have it set to manual, you can obscure any sensitive info, of course!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Most probably, your proxy is blocking the WebSocket protocol. Chrome before version 14 and IE don't support it, so they are not affected.

Go to the URL `about:config`, search for the key `network.websocket.enabled` and switch it to `false`.

Comment: This worked for me, FF 14.0.1. problem was specifically with stackoverflow.com!

Comment: Hoorah! This has fixed my problem, at last I can use stackoverflow without having to resort to IE! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I Just tried the suggestion in the accepted answer and I'm afraid it didn't fix my problem, as well as these other suggestion which also didn't work: http://nasarabna.wordpress.com/2010/03/03/firefox-keeps-prompting-for-proxy-authentication/ (These solutions may be currently outdated)

However, while browsing the `aboug:config` page I found this entry:

```
signon.autologin.proxy
```

If this is set to `TRUE` the prompt does not appear anymore.

BTW: It does only work if you log in at least once. If you cancel it, it keeps appearing.

And, as a consequence, if you use the private browsing feature (I use it at work, for personal stuff: e-mail, etc.), every time you start a new private session you have to accept the login prompt. Not a big problem though...

Answer (score 2):

I've been having the same issue for a while now. It's a bug specific to Firefox, and only when accessing Facebook addresses through a proxy. This page itself, for instance, brings up the dialog a total of 10 times, taking 10 clicks before I can dismiss it and go about my business.

I have since downgraded to Firefox 4.0.1, which fixed the issue. It's not a great workaround, but it's there.

EDIT: It turns out that last bit was premature - I've now started experiencing the same problem on 4.0.1.

Comment: Facebook: "We're on to you, jcarter!" :P

Comment: This problem is quickly driving me insane - what's worse is that Chrome flatly refuses to install on this machine, so don't have the option of using it in the interim.

Comment: Which operating system? If Windows, you can try [Google Chrome Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable).

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the installation problem, but I still have a persistant issue with Chrome where it becomes stuck "Sending request..." and never loads the page. That's a story for another SU question though.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox 8 added [Origin tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/img#attr-crossorigin) for images, which has caused some specific [proxy issues](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=701029). If Facebook works for you with Firefox 7, I would say it's a bug in Firefox.